# foreign key constraints not enforced on MariaDB, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Even though I thought I understood the logic in foreign keys, I cannot make this small example to work.

In this example, I am inserting values that **break** the foreign key constrain. I would expect to receive an error -- but I do not.

```
/* info about my server */
select version();
show variables where variable_name = "foreign_key_checks";

/* example starts here */
create table foo (id int primary key) engine = 'InnoDB';
insert into foo values (1);
create table bar (id int primary key references foo(id)) engine = 'InnoDB';
insert into bar values (2); -- should complain here, but does not
commit;
select * from foo;
select * from bar;
```

This results in:

```
MariaDB [test]> select version();
+-----------------+
| version()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.3.21-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> show variables where variable_name = "foreign_key_checks";
+--------------------+-------+
| Variable_name      | Value |
+--------------------+-------+
| foreign_key_checks | ON    |
+--------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [test]> create table foo (id int primary key) engine = 'InnoDB';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.358 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into foo values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.040 sec)

MariaDB [test]> create table bar (id int primary key references foo(id)) engine = 'InnoDB';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.205 sec)

MariaDB [test]> insert into bar values (2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.024 sec)

MariaDB [test]> commit;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from foo;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select * from bar;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

So since "It looks like [my] post is mostly code; please add some more details.", let me paraphrase here. In the above,

1. I checked that my server is set up to enforce foreign key contraints,
2. I explicitly use the InnoDB engine -- the one actually enforcing foreign key contraints.

Despite that, `bar` contains an `id` of 2 that is not present in `foo`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand why referential integrity isn't being enforced either. I wonder if adding the foreign key reference at the table level instead of the column level would make a difference?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson You are right! Adding the constrain at the table label makes the insert into `bar` fail as expected. Interesting...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem lies in this tricky behavior that is in fact highlighted in the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-table/#column-definitions) (emphasis mine):

> MariaDB accepts the REFERENCES clause in ALTER TABLE and CREATE TABLE column definitions, but that syntax does nothing. MariaDB simply parses it **without returning any error or warning**, for compatibility with other DBMS's. Before MariaDB 10.2.1 this was also true for CHECK constraints. Only the syntax for indexes described below creates foreign keys.

In short, one must declare foreign key contraints on separate lines if they are to be enforced (thanks @Honeyboy).

Answer (score 0):

insert into foo values (1);
create table bar (id int not null primary key, id_foo int, foreign key (id_foo) references foo(id)); should works for you.

insert into bar values (2,1);

Comment: Can you explain why the OP's test failed, but yours worked?

Comment: You are adding a value that does not break the foreign key constrain. You missed the point of my question.